# Bug in simple text editor (Python)

Tags: python

As a beginner creating a simple python text editor I have encountered a confusing bug in which I am able to print out the text file with the read_file() function when I first open it, but after I amend the text file using write_file(), reading the file again simple returns whitespace.

Additionally, any critique of my code would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
import os


def main():
    file = open_file()
    quit = False
    while quit == False:
        print('Current file open is {}'.format(file.name))
        print('(\'read\', \'write\', \'rename\', \'change file\', \'quit\',)')
        action = raw_input('> ')
        if str(action) == 'read':
            read_file(file)
        elif str(action) == 'write':
            file = write_file(file)
        elif str(action) == 'rename':
            file = rename(file)
        elif str(action) == 'change file':
            file.close()
            open_file()
        elif str(action) == 'quit':
            break
        else:
            print('Incorrect action.')



def open_file():
    print('Create/open a file')
    filename = raw_input('Filename: ')
    try:
        file = open(str(filename), 'r+')
        return file
    except:
        print('An error occured')
        return open_file()



def read_file(file):
    try:
        print('{}, {}'.format(file.name, file))
        print(file.read())
    except:
        print('An error occured')
    return None


def write_file(file):
    print('Type to start writing to your file.')
    #read_file(file)
    add_text = raw_input('> ')
    file.write(str(add_text))
    return file


def rename(file):
    new_name = raw_input('New file name: ')
    os.rename(file.name, str(new_name))
    return file


main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **file** is a predefined package; please don't use it for a variable name, or you may have trouble getting to some of the facilities.  Try **my_file** or just the C-language **fp** (for "file pointer").

After you write new information to the file, your position pointer (bookmark) is likely at the end of the file.  Reading more will get you nowhere.  You need to either close and reopen the file, or call fp.seek() to get to the desired location.  For instance, **fp.seek(0)** will reset the pointer to the start of the file.

Comment: I'd say using `file` as a variable name is fine.  It's rarely used and it only affects the scope it's used in.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to reading and writing files in python, if you do not call the method `(filename).close()` after making a change to a file, it will not save anything to it because it thinks you're still a) writing to it or b) still reading it!

Hope this helps!